# Running a for loop through 2 arrays of different lengths and index manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, indexing

I need to run a for loop through 2 arrays of different lengths. One array is 8760 by 1 and the other is 10 by 1. If a value in the short array is equal to to the index of a value in the long array, I don't want to change anything. If the index of a value in the long array isn't equal to a value in the short array, I want to set it equal to zero. I know the code I have is wrong, but it's a start. I couldn't attach the longer array, but it could be random values for now.

I = np.array([4993, 4994, 4995, 5016, 5017, 5018, 5019, 5042, 5043, 5066])

```
import numpy as np

A = np.loadtxt('A.txt')
I = np.loadtxt('I.txt')

for i in A:
    for j in I:
        if A[j] != I[j]:
            i = 0
```

Comment: Look into `np.in1d` for an easier way or `np.searchsorted` for a not-so-easier but efficient way.

Comment: @Divakar FYI now there's also [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Hmm new stuffs, exciting!

Comment: I'd almost want to add an answer, but it's clear from your code example that there are very fundamental issues there. You would probably benefit from reading a python tutorial if you haven't done so already.

Comment: np.in1d doesn't appear to let me change values to zero based on the index after looking at the documentation

Comment: `np.in1d` or even better, `np.isin`, can give you a logical index which can then be used to set the elements you want to zero.

Comment: ```If the index of a value in the long array ...``` - are you comparing values in the short array to the indices of the long array or the values in the long array?

Comment: Given your `I`, are you wanting to set all values of `A` to `0` (e.g. assign `A[5] = 0`) except, for example, `A[4993]` will be unchanged, and so on for indices in `I`?

Comment: Yes. If the index of 'A' is equal to a value in 'I', I want 'A' unchanged. If the index of 'A' is anything other than 4993, 4994, 4995, 5016, 5017, 5018, 5019, 5042, 5043, 5066, I want the value of 'A' set equal to zero.

Comment: I've just added a benchmarking section to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main principle**

When you need a `for` loop to walk across the indices of an array, use a "counted" loop-- a loop that iterates across a set of integers. Use `for index in range(len(`your list`)`.

**Your specific problem**

Given your `I`, I think you are asking to set all values of `A` to `0` (e.g. assign `A[5] = 0`) except, for example, `A[4993]` will be unchanged, and so on for indices in `I`.

```
good_elements_indices = I
all_elements = A
for all_elements_index in range(len(all_elements)):
    if all_elements_index not in good_elements_index:
        A[all_elements_index] = 0
```

**Additional comments**

- Python style uses variable names that are lower case with underscores between words and no abbreviations. Hence I renamed `I` and `A`. See [PEP 8: Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- The `in` operator is core Python. Because you're already importing `numpy` and your `good_elements_index` aka `I` is already a `numpy.array` object, it is faster but less general to use `numpy.isin` function as suggested by `mrcl`.
- Your question talked about "running a for loop through 2 arrays." That suggests not one `for` loop but two `for` loops, nested, as your question's code shows. The `in` operator actually iterates like a `for` loop across the list testing for existence within the set.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea of `numpy` being *"no loops"* I'd like to show how it
is possible to perform the task proposed by the OP w/o any (explicit)
loop.

We are going to use the extended addressing capabilities of `numpy`
to let it deal, at its speed, with the data manipulation details.

To present an example, I need to have some `data` and a list, or
vector, here named `persisting`, of the indices corresponding to those
values that are requested to persist in the modified `data` array at
the end of our procedure.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(10)
persisting = [4,8,1,0]
```

Given these preliminaries, we can compute an `held` array that holds
all the `data` elements that we want to persist, [indexing the `data`
array using the `persisting`
array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays)

```
held = data[persisting]
```

The `data` array can be filled with zeros at full speed using the
array method
[`.fill()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html#numpy-ndarray-fill)
and eventually the elements saved in `held` can be restored into their
original places, using again extended addressing, this time on the left
of the assignment.

```
data.fill(0)
data[persisting] = held
print(data) #>>> [0 1 0 0 4 0 0 0 8 0]
```

The procedure sketched above may or may not be faster than other
approaches depending on the `len()` of the array you are manipulating
and on how much of it, respectively, you are zero-filling rather than
keeping the previous value.  If yours is a production problem you have
to consider benchmarking the diverse approaches that you've been
suggested.

#### Benchmarking

I have timed the methods proposed in the accepted answer and in mine.  In the following the transcript of an IPython session that documents my procedure.

The results printed are the length of the data array, the length of the indices array, the time (in seconds) that is used (averaged over 7 repetitions), to execute each one of the two functions.

```
In [38]: import numpy as np

In [39]: def accepted(A, I):
    ...:     good_elements_indices = I
    ...:     all_elements = A
    ...:     for all_elements_index in range(len(all_elements)):
    ...:         if all_elements_index not in good_elements_indices:
    ...:             A[all_elements_index] = 0.0
    ...:             

In [40]: def alternate(a, i):
    ...:     held = a[i]
    ...:     a.fill(0.0)
    ...:     a[i] = held
    ...:     

In [41]: for length in (100, 10000, 1000000):
    ...:     a = np.arange(length)
    ...:     for remain in (10, 100, 10000, length//2):
    ...:         if remain < length:
    ...:             i = np.random.choice(length, remain)
    ...:             acc_t = %timeit -q -o  accepted(a, i)
    ...:             alt_t = %timeit -q -o alternate(a, i)
    ...:             print('%10d, %10d: %e, %e;'%(
    ...:                    length, remain, acc_t.average, alt_t.average))
    ...:                    
       100,         10: 1.506336e-04, 1.126085e-06;
       100,         50: 1.663167e-04, 1.385859e-06;
     10000,         10: 1.539412e-02, 5.308621e-06;
     10000,        100: 2.198021e-02, 6.056105e-06;
     10000,       5000: 2.995333e-01, 3.775863e-05;
   1000000,         10: 1.524685e+00, 1.596268e-03;
   1000000,        100: 2.187460e+00, 1.599069e-03;
   1000000,      10000: 7.067548e+01, 1.770094e-03;
^C---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Note that I had to interrupt the timing procedure because `%timeit` computes the average over seven repetitions, meaning that the last row took more than 8' to complete...

I have to say that the accepted answer could be sped up quite easily, but I think that having to deal with loops and tests it will be however slower.